# MySQL Limit number of records to 5 unique values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, limit

i am trying to create a leaderboard based on numbers of kills in a game where it shows top 5 ranking players (people with the same number of kills are in the same rank).

How do i get all records up until rank 5 position (all records until a max of 5 unique values in a column(kills)).

I hope that makes sense.

The query will also need to take into account the map. For Example: WHERE map = 'map_name'

For Example:

Table:

```
Name, Map, Kills
user0 - map2 - 30
user1 - map1 - 30
user2 - map1 - 27
user3 - map1 - 54
user4 - map1 - 34
user5 - map1 - 34
user6 - map1 - 27
user7 - map1 - 22
user8 - map1 - 22
user9 - map1 - 31
user10 - map1 - 21
user11 - map1 - 27
user12 - map2 - 34
```

Result Needed (all players / records within the top 5 ranks with the map name map1):

```
1. user3 - 54
2. user4 - 34
   user5 - 34
3. user9 - 31
4. user1 - 30
5. user2 - 27
   user6 - 27
   user11 - 27
```

So far i have: `SELECT * FROM`records`WHERE`map`= 'map1' ORDER BY`kills`DESC`

but i need to limit the number of rows returned to only the amount needed for the `top 5 ranks`, rather then all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query :

```
     SELECT * FROM records WHERE 
    map = 'map1' and  kills in (SELECT * FROM 
(select Kills from records  where map = 'map1' group by Kills order by kills desc limit 0,5) 
as x)  order by Kills desc
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c472/12/0)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this query actually works, for the posted question.

Comment: please run the fiddle to verify the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it without top/limit features:

```
SELECT ... FROM T t
WHERE t.map = ? AND t.kills <= (
    select max(t2.kills) from T t2
    where t2.map = t.map and (
        select count(distinct t3.kills) from T t3
        where t3.map = t2.map and t3.kills <= t2.kills
    ) <= 5
)
```