# Order by clause of sql not working for second table which is in relation with first table

Tags: php, mysql

I have got two table `users` and `friends_in`.`Users` table is my main table where every registered users information are stored.`Friends_in` table is where one friend to another friend request sended information are stored as column `from_fren` and `to_fren`.Now I was comparing my `friends_in` table `from_fren` column data with the `users` table `people_name` column.I first fetched data from `users` table in a function like below :-

```
    $query = "SELECT person_name FROM users"; 
                           try 
                                { 
                                    $stmts = $db->prepare($query); 
                                    $result = $stmts->execute(); 
                                    if($result == true)
                                    {
                                      $done = true;
                                    }
                                } 
                              catch(PDOException $ex) 
                                  { 
                                      die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
                                  }
                              if($done)
                                {
                                  $rows = $stmts->fetchAll();
                                  return $rows;
                                } 
                } 

  $data = forallUsers();
```

Now, i got my all user detail so, after that I used a `foreach` loop and compared the `users` table and its column `person_name` with `friends_in` table with its column `from_fren` like below :-

```
   foreach($data as $row){
   require('My database info is here');
    $done_two = false;
    $other = $row['person_name'];
      $realuser = $_SESSION['username'] ['username'];

          $query = 'SELECT from_fren,to_fren FROM friend_in WHERE (from_fren = :ot and to_fren = :me)';
              $query_paramt = array( 
                 ':ot' => $other,
                 ':me' => $realuser
                );

                try 
                  { 
                        $stmts = $db->prepare($query); 
                        $results = $stmts->execute($query_paramt); 
                        if($results == true)
                          {
                              $done_two = true;
                          }
                  }   
                catch(PDOException $ex) 
                        { 
                            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
                        }
    if($done_two) {
                     //do something.... 
                  }
   }
```

I wanna select `from_fren` and `to_fren` two columns from `friend_in` table.`$other` is the person who sends fren request and `$realuser` is the person who is receiving the fren proposal(it will be session user).

****BUT MY MAIN PROBLEM IS THAT****

When i display this on my site I get data of `from_fren` and `to_fren` as `ORDER BY` id `ASC` of `users` table.I mean I wanna show latest friend_request information to `session_user`.Data i get successfully but the problem is that those data are some how displayed in a `order` by id `ASC` of `users` table.

How can i show  `session_user` new fren request in this case??I tried and made a new column in `friend_in` table by name `latest` and set type `datetime` on database and by php `now()`.I change my past code and which now work for storing current `datetime` when one user sends fren req to another.After that i used `ORDER BY` clause on that `friend_in` table `latest` column `DSEC`.This one is my new code :-

```
   foreach($data as $row){
   require('My database info is here');
    $done_two = false;
    $other = $row['person_name'];
      $realuser = $_SESSION['username'] ['username'];

          $query = 'SELECT from_fren,to_fren FROM friend_in WHERE (from_fren = :ot and to_fren = :me) ORDER BY latest DESC';
              $query_paramt = array( 
                 ':ot' => $other,
                 ':me' => $realuser
                );

                try 
                  { 
                        $stmts = $db->prepare($query); 
                        $results = $stmts->execute($query_paramt); 
                        if($results == true)
                          {
                              $done_two = true;
                          }
                  }   
                catch(PDOException $ex) 
                        { 
                            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
                        }
    if($done_two) {
                     //do something.... 
                  }
   }
```

But I am still not able to get latest fren req to that session user.Still that `friend_in` table column data are working like `ORDER BY id ASC` of that `users` table.How can I make work my second code?

Comment: in first sql use `SELECT person_name FROM users order by user_id desc ` so the latest will come first then while using in `foreach` also you will get latest data first.or use `order by id desc` in `second sql`.

Comment: Doing that didn't worked bro and I guess it will not cause higher `id` will appear at first  no matter if the lower `id` sended the fren req first due to the desc higher id appear at first :/

Comment: you want higher id's to come first or any thing else.

Comment: I want to use where clause which get me latest data from that friend_in table by its friend request datetime.

Comment: I have stored datetime on a column named `latest` which store's datatime as `2015-11-01 11:16:28` now i want to select the latest time and display it by desc.

Comment: I mean if a user has three friend request he will get data from latest time larger to small :) Is it possible?

Comment: then use order by datatime desc limit 1; if only one record required otherwise remove limit part.

Comment: or try to create a sqlfiddle here:http://sqlfiddle.com/ for second table.

Comment: oh u mean by latest?cause my column name is not datetime its latest bro

Comment: yes i mean the respective column name.

Comment: bro i did that it too and its still not working :/ `order by id Asc` of that `users` table is any how taking action on this second table query too :/

Comment: create the sql fiddle with some sample data.

Comment: `SELECT from_fren,to_fren FROM friend_in WHERE (from_fren = :ot and to_fren = :me) ORDER BY latest DESC` it's now only working for ASC of users but when higher value send request first they are still not latest.

Comment: it should work.give a try to `ORDER BY date(latest) DESC`

Comment: is my code correct bro? i mean after that where clause i'm using the order clause is it fine?

Comment: yes it is correct ...this is how we do.

Comment: bro but i knew that order by clause of second table query is working as long as it matches with order by clause of first table .

Comment: default my data of first table are fetched in ASC order so...now when i try to use order by or where anything on second table it is concerning with that first table which is creating this issue :/

Comment: hello see this fiddle link of my answer and try to create similar from your data and share the link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449695/mysql-limit-number-of-records-to-5-unique-values-in-one-column/33450007#33450007

Comment: which data?u mean first table?

Comment: then why not select the data from first table with `having max(columnName) group by user_id`

Comment: which ever is giving you problem.

Comment: As long as that order by clause taking effect on second table I can't make my work bro how can i order my data from second table?1,2,3,4 id with people_name a,b,c,d are comming and now when d send req before a  d isn't selected as latest its the case here happening :/ and its all happening because of that table first :/

Comment: show your first table structure and few records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT person_name FROM users` get all users and order by id desc, when your loop it in foreach, you always get the user with higher id rather than latest in second query.

I think there is no need to get all users from table users and then loop them, just try to use sql like this:

```
select from_fren, to_fren, users.person_name from friend_in, users where person_name = from_fren and to_fren = :me order by latest desc limit 1
```

Comment: wow bro it works fine :D It now presents the latest fren req.Data which are now fetched are  `order by latest desc` which mean it's now fetching data by latest time.It was what I wanted to do like from my earlier code.Is it join or union?Can u explain me in little deep what exactly above sql code did?